# UML diagram in XMI Format

Tags: xml, uml, xmi

My question is: is there a document or other that explains how to represent the elements of uml diagram in universal xmi format ( for example in the class diagram how te represent a class, attribute.... in xmi format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagram definition and diagram interchange are separate specifications from the usual XMI. You can find them here: http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/1.0/ .

Comment: Diagram definition it is for the graphical representation I think!!

Comment: That's the only way to transfer diagrams between tools. If that's not what you asked for, please clarify your question.

Comment: I search the standard structure of XMI file representing uml diagrams (example :how to represent a class, attribute .... in an XMI file)

Comment: You cannot represent diagrams in normal XMI. You need to look at those links.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my 2 cent: XMI has been defined by OMG which is a consortium of companies. Though one might think that it is some kind of standard it actually lets lots of freedom to tool vendors implementing their own flavor of XMI. And as can be seen in practice each vendor took that freedom so model exchange is something non-trivial.